# HTML/CSS Dropdown Menu: The second list item in my code is overlapping the first

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am making a drop down menu using only HTML and CSS. The menu components are successfully dropping down and everything looks good except when there are two or more components to an element. Then the second one covers the first. I was able to fix this by putting "position: absolute" in "#nav ul li:hover ul" (code below), but then the first item does not clear the menu bar.

Sorry for the terrible description.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body background="Images/Sun.jpg">
    <div class="center" id="main">
        <div class="center" id="header">
            <br/><p>JOSEPH T. IOSUE</p><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="center" id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">PYTHON</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" download>RESUME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">joe.iosue@yahoo.com</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">301-980-9525</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:white;clear:both;background-color:#00CCFF">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
body {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#main {
    background-color: #00CCFF;
    width: 70%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
#header p {
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header * {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
}
#nav * {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1vw;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #00CCFF;
}
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00CCFF;
    padding: 1vw 3vw 1vw 3vw;
}
#nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}    
#nav ul li:hover ul li a {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff6666;
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code. I have slightly modified your css.

```css
body {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#main {
    background-color: #00CCFF;
    width: 70%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
#header p {
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header * {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
}
#nav * {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1vw;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #00CCFF;
}
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00CCFF;
    padding: 1vw 3vw 1vw 3vw;
}
#nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
} 
#nav ul li ul li{
    background: none;
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
#nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff6666;
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center" id="main">
        <div class="center" id="header">
            <br/><p>JOSEPH T. IOSUE</p><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="center" id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">PYTHON</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" download>RESUME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">joe.iosue@yahoo.com</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">301-980-9525</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:white;clear:both;background-color:#00CCFF">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pls replace your entire css with this one

```
body {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#main {
    background-color: #00CCFF;
    width: 70%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
#header p {
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header * {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
}
#nav * {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1vw;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #00CCFF;
}
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00CCFF;
    padding: 1vw 3vw 1vw 3vw;
}
#nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}    
#nav ul li:hover ul li a {
background-color: #ff0000;
    float: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff6666;
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
}

#nav ul li li {
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main dropdown trigger should be #main, the dropdown #nav and #header both have the MAIN PARENT #main. Set #main 'position: relative;' and set a height let's say 50px 'height: 50px;' THEN set #nav 'position: relative; top: 100%;' and the height of #header to 50px as #main.

```
    #main { position: relative; height: 50px; }
    #header, #nav { position: absolute; }
    #header { width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; }
    #nav { top: 100%; left: 0; min-height: 100px; } /*set it to left or right 0*/
```

Now the dropdown should trigger on `#main:hover #nav { display: block !important; }`
Now you must style your dropdown as you want

Answer (score 0):

**Modify the below css :**

```
#nav * {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1vw;
    margin: auto;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: block;
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Index</title>
            <style>     
                body {
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: 100% auto;
                }
                #main {
                    background-color: #00ccff;
                    width: 70%;
                }
                ul {
                    list-style: outside none none;
                }
                #header {
                    background-color: blue;
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 100%;
                }
                #header p {
                    font-size: 3vw;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                #header * {
                    margin: 0;
                }
                #nav {
                    width: 100%;
                }
                #nav * {
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-size: 1vw;
                    margin: auto;
                }
                #nav a {
                    background-color: #00ccff;
                    padding: 1vw 3vw;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
                #nav ul li {
                    position: relative;
                }
                #nav ul li a {
                    color: white;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                #nav ul li ul {
                    display: none;
                    padding: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                }       
                #nav ul li ul li {
                    display: block;
                }
                #nav ul li:hover ul {
                    clear: both;
                    display: block;
                    float: none;
                }
                #nav ul li:hover ul li a {
                    background-color: #ff0000;
                    display: block;
                }
                #nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
                    background-color: #ff6666;
                }
                .center {
                    margin: auto;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body background="Images/Sun.jpg">
            <div class="center" id="main">
                <div class="center" id="header">
                    <br/><p>JOSEPH T. IOSUE</p><br/>
                </div>
                <div class="center" id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">PYTHON</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" download>RESUME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">joe.iosue@yahoo.com</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">301-980-9525</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>               
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:white;clear:both;background-color:#00CCFF">
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```